# What data type, scheme, and how many bits should be used to store a FOREX price?

Tags: c++, price, forex, cstdint

A typical FOREX price would be carried out to the 4th decimal place; for example, the current price of the GBP against the USD today is **1.2515**. I have seen this price carried out to more decimal places.

This is really a two-part question.

---

### First

There are two schemes that I am considering:

**a)** A floating-point type; `double` jumps to mind. I'm a bit concerned about rounding error here.
**b)** An integer type, storing the decimal and integer pieces separately.

**Any other realistic options?**

**Of those** ( above )**, which one is correct?**

---

### Second

In either scheme, I would precisely specify the number of bits used via the `<cstdint>` library.

**How many bits makes sense?**

I'm looking to balance accuracy, memory/storage cost, and (of course) performance.

Thx, Keith :^)

Comment: Never use `double` (or alike) floating point values to represent money. The bookkeepers will be thankful, believe me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ with due respect, this question's similarity is just an illusion. The **FOREX `PriceDOMAIN` quotes are by far a different story** than a (just similarly looking) problem of generic representation of monetary values. Whereas the underlying motivation for the smartest memory mapping is close each one to the other, **there are major & important differences, in the FOREX domain**, that the question you have referred to, is **principally missing to have, as such rules do not exist in the general purpose monetary values number representation (a.k.a. accounting). Better opt to REOPEN, Sir**

Comment: @user3666197 Feel free to vote for reopening.